# Polymorphics association for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a scenario where i have Page model now each page can be of type one. Lets say page can be of type videos or images and many other types. As video and image have their own models i want to make this page as polymorphic. Is it possible in rails?

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pageable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :page, :as => :pageable, :class_name => 'Video'
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :page, :as => :pageable, :class_name => 'Image'
end
```

Is this valid? My requirement is that during page creation, one of the type need to be selected and then on selection it forwards to video or image form.

Answer (score 0):

Its valid. This is what the polymorphic association is provided for. You don't need the "`:class_name => 'Video'` though, you can safely drop it.

Comment: thanks Swanand, but in my scenario, Page owns the video or image, mostly in polymorphic association the polymorphic object is owned by others e.g like Post or Article has comments, in this case comment is  being polymorphic. My above snippet also suggests that page is being owned by images or videos but its other way around. I just want to ask that the above snippet will work for my scenario or not???? If it won't then what changes i need to do for that.